# Consul 1.8.4 ui not loading as it is expected

Tags: consul

There is a scenario that I'm working on and that is clustering Consul for Service Discovery. I have 3 physical machines to create a cluster. I follow this [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/deployment-guide) to design my cluster. At the end of the day, this is the result of `consul members`:
[image]

** I don't see the leader election or something like that, strange!!

There is an error on connection to `Consul UI`, as long as I enabled `ui` in the configuration. The error said

> The Backend responded with an error, Error 500
> You may have visited a URL that is loading an unknown resource, so you can try going back to the root or try re-submitting your ACL Token/SecretID by going back to ACLs.

Then I realized may it's important to configure ACL, so I added these lines to my configuration file

```
acl {
   enabled        = true
   default_policy = "deny"
   down_policy    = "extend-cache"
}
```

After this `consul members` command said

> Error retrieving members: Unexpected response code: 403 (ACL not found)

and `consul acl bootstrap` command said

> Failed ACL bootstrapping: Unexpected response code: 500 (The ACL system is currently in legacy mode.)

Good to mention that all the configuration for servers is coming from this [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/deployment-guide).

So what's going on here?

Comment: It sounds like the cluster may not have elected a leader. Can you check if a leader is elected using `consul operator raft list-peers`? The error from `consul acl bootstrap` about the system being in legacy mode is likely because Consul cannot determine whether all servers support the new ACL model. See https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/5218#issuecomment-453568856 for more detail.

Comment: Logfile in `/var/log/consul/` will have these errors if that is the case:


    2021-02-09T15:50:38.634+0100 [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No cluster leader"
    2021-02-09T15:50:39.484+0100 [ERROR] agent: Coordinate update error: error="No cluster leader"

Comment: You also need to create ACL tokens for the Consul agents in your environment. You can follow the process in https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/access-control-setup-production#apply-individual-tokens-to-agents, or the following. 1) Create tokens for each node using `consul acl token create -node-identity=<node_name>`.  2) Configure the tokens in [`acl.tokens.agent`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#acl_tokens_agent) and `acl.tokens.default`. 3) Restart Consul.